# plotting pdf in gnuplot : error Cannot open load file 'stat.inc'

Tags: pdf, gnuplot

I am learning how to plot pdf in gnuplot. The code is sourced from 
    http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/random.html

the code is

```
unset contour
unset parametric

load "stat.inc"

print ""
print "Simple Monte Carlo simulation"
print ""
print "The first curve is a histogram where the binned frequency of occurence"
print "of a pseudo random variable distributed according to the normal"
print "(Gaussian) law is scaled such that the histogram converges to the"
print "normal probability density function with increasing number of samples"
print "used in the Monte Carlo simulation.  The second curve is the normal"
print "probability density function with unit variance and zero mean."
print ""
nsamp = 5000
binwidth = 20
xlow = -3.0
xhigh = 3.0
scale = (binwidth/(xhigh-xlow)) 
# Generate N random data points.
set print "random.tmp"
do for [i=1:nsamp] {
print sprintf("%8.5g %8.5g", invnorm(rand(0)), (1.0*scale/nsamp))
}
unset print
#
set samples 200
tstring(n) = sprintf("Histogram of %d random samples from a univariate\nGaussian PDF     with unit variance and zero mean", n)
set title tstring(nsamp)
set key
set grid
set terminal png
set output "x.png"
set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [0:0.45]
bin(x) = (1.0/scale)*floor(x*scale)
plot "random.tmp" using (bin($1)):2 smooth frequency with steps title "scaled bin frequency", normal(x,0,1) with lines title "Gaussian p.d.f."
```

I get the error

```
Cannot open load file 'stat.inc'
"stat.inc", line 4: util.c: No such file or directory
```

The version of gnuplot I am using is gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0.
Please help as I am unable to locate this particular file or run the code on ubuntu platform.

Answer (score 1):

you find all that file in the source release of gnuplot.
You can download it from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/latest/download?source=files)

you'll find the stat.inc in the demo directory

Comment: installing the package given at sourceforge link didnt help. the same error persists.

Comment: you should now have a file named stat.inc in the demo folder of the gnuplot package you downloaded. Run your script from that directory or (better copy the file stat.inc in your script folder)